# not supported on forward only result sets en Java

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy tratando de llenar un JTable con los registros que tiene una tabla en mi base de datos en SQL.

Recibo este error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested
>   operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Stack Trace:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.throwNotScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:414)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetIsScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:437)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.last(SQLServerResultSet.java:1477)
    at logicas.Logica_usuarios.tableRegistros(Logica_usuarios.java:28)
    at vistas.Vista_usuarios.tableRegistros(Vista_usuarios.java:38)
    at vistas.Vista_usuarios.<init>(Vista_usuarios.java:117)
    at vistas.Vista_usuarios$1.run(Vista_usuarios.java:56)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Código JTable:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(12, 73, 598, 187);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        tableRegistros();
```

Procedimiento tableRegistros();

```
void tableRegistros() {
        try {
            Logica_usuarios l_users = new Logica_usuarios();
            DefaultTableModel model;
            model = l_users.tableRegistros();
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: Vista_usuarios.tableRegistros()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

Código de la conexión en SQL y del llenado (public class Logica_usuarios):

```
public DefaultTableModel tableRegistros() {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;

        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            String [] titulosColumnas = {"Nombre", "Apellido", "Usuario", "Contraseña"};

            rs.last();
            int filas = rs.getRow();
            rs.first();

            Object [][] registros = new Object[filas][titulosColumnas.length]; 

            int i = 0;
            do {
                registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
                registros[i][3] = rs.getString("usuario");
                registros[i][4] = rs.getString("contrasena");
                i++;
            } while (rs.next());

            model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_usuarios.tableRegistros()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return model;
    }
```

No logro encontrar la solución, espero puedan ayudarme a descubrir qué hice mal. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Saca ese "model=new DefaultTableModel(registros,titulosColumnas);" del try-catch y no te dira nada (y si sale con otro error, pues bueno, ya no sera lo del "null table model")

Comment: Hola, como dijiste, el error Cannot set a null TableModel se ha ido, pero, sigo recibiendo el error The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets. Este error viene de mi "public class Logica_usuarios" y no tengo idea de qué puede ser.

Comment: Creo que vas a tener que hacer una pregunta aparte con mas detalles, porque por comentarios va a ser dificil detectar ese error...

Comment: @TwoDent he modificado mi post inicial para que la duda este bien aclarada, espero puedas ayudarme si tienes alguna idea de que significa ese error, yo sigo perdido.

Comment: ¿Donde está el stack trace del error?

Comment: Hola @sstan edité mi post principal con el Stack Trace, gracias de antemano, espero puedas ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el stack trace, el error proviene de esta sentencia:

```
rs.last();
```

Por defecto, los result sets son *forward only*, o sea, que solo los puedes leer un registro a la vez y hacia adelante nada más. LLamadas como `last()` o `first()` no funcionarán.

Si usaras un `PreparedStatement` pudieras cambiar el tipo de result set que obtienes para poder habilitar estos métodos, pero no creo que valga la pena hacer esto en tu caso.

En tu caso, la única razón por la que haces esta llamada es porque estás tratando de determinar la cantidad de registros de antemano.

Yo te sugiero cambiar la lógica para que no necesites esta información de antemano. Esto lo puedes hacer cambiando el array por un `ArrayList` y convirtiéndolo a un array al mero final.

De paso, aunque no tuvieras ese problema, ibas a enfrentarte a otros después. El código está lleno de errores. Por ejemplo, estás usando un `do-while` lo que es incorrecto porque tratas de leer el primer registro antes de llamar `rs.next()`. También, tu uso de `registros` dentro del bucle causaría un `NullPointerException`. También estás asumiendo que el primer índice de los arrays es `1`, esto es incorrecto.

Aquí te dejo un extracto de código que corrige estos problemas:

```
String [] titulosColumnas = {"Nombre", "Apellido", "Usuario", "Contraseña"};
ArrayList<Object[]> registros = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

while (rs.next()) {
    registros.add(new Object[] {
        rs.getString("nombre"),
        rs.getString("apellido"),
        rs.getString("usuario"),
        rs.getString("contrasena")
    });
}

model = new DefaultTableModel(registros.toArray(new Object[0][]), titulosColumnas);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada. Nunca me iba a imaginar que tenía tantos errores, son cosas que si alguien no te lo explica, nunca los aprendes a detectar. Tengo una pregunta acerca del ArrayList tipo Object[]. 1. Por qué no se le indica el tamaño de filas y columnas?. 2. Por qué al final, cuando pasamos el registros.toArray, indicas que Object[0][], por qué [0]?, qué quiere decir ese 0?, y por qué el segundo [] esta vacío?. Sé muy poco sobre Object, espero no te moleste y gracias por todo nuevamente.

Comment: Respuestas breves e incompletas: 1) No se indica la cantidad de registros porque `ArrayList` está diseñado para poder manejar una cantidad *variable* de registros. 2) El `[0]` especifica un array vacío. Es una peculiaridad de como se debe llamar al método `ArrayList.toArray()`. Puedes buscar mas información al respecto. El `[]` es común en declaraciones de arrays multi dimensionales. Cuando se declaran, solo se necesita especificar el tamaño de la primera dimensión, las demás dimensiones pueden quedar indefinidas inicialmente. Para mas info, busca sobre el tema de arrays multi dimensionales.